# Including a remote script causes my page to appear blank until touched

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

My page is hanging up with a blank/white screen until I touch it. The problem goes away when I comment out the following line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us/sandbox/js/Widgets.js?sellerId=ANQ73XOZ7PBIK'></script>
```

I am able to display an alert box both before and after the above line of code. Also, the problem goes away as soon as I re-load the app! It's only the first time the app is run that I have a problem.

My page uses PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. I have tried moving the above line of code to before/after the PhoneGap/jQuery stuff. No difference.

Thank you for your help :)

P.S. I have also seen this problem occur off and on when loading my page within Android's regular browser. So I'm thinking it's more than a PhoneGap issue.

P.S.S Here is the page link https://www.mytrafficman.net/app/android/

Comment: Are you testing off a local url? (i.e. `file:///d/code/myapp/index.html`) ?

Comment: No. Also the problem goes away whenever I reload my app. It's only the first time it loads we have a blank screen, every time.

Comment: Anything in the console? Does this happen in all browsers or just one?

Comment: When the screen is black, can you check using an inspector, whether your html tag has a display: none on it?

Comment: How would I use an inspector within a app's WebView?